# SSIS and IBM MQ Series integration

Tags: ssis, integration, ibm-mq

I am in the process of exploring integration between SSIS and IBM MQ Series. Can some point me to some artical for integration.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the "Message Queue Task" in conjunction with some other host bridge.  Here's what I found while trolling the Internet:

SSIS does not support loading into/from IBM MQ Series directly out of the box. ETI is the only known Microsoft partner or other 3rd party that can handle reading and writing to IBM MQ Series.  This is handled via native sequential (MQSeries Queue Message)through their Built-to-Order connectivity process. SSIS customers also have the below ways of integrating their solutions with IBM MQ Series:

1.Microsoft’s MSMQ-MQ Series Bridge that comes with Host Integration Server. MSMQ Task in Control Flow in SSIS can be used along with the bridge, which provides connectionless, store-and-forward messaging across messaging systems and computing platforms throughout the network.

2.Using BizTalk’s MQ Series Adapter to push/pull messages into/out of SSIS Data Flow Engine via various exchange mechanisms : in-memory: script component, or staging : exchanging messages via the file system or directly writing it into SQL Server tables and use a data source component to read them.

3.Using the extensibility story in SSIS: build an MQ Series source/destination custom/script component directly interfacing with MQ Series native libraries.

You can find the original website [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1952.ssis-connectors-with-ibm-mq-series-websphere-mq.aspx).

Here's a description of the "Message Queue Task" that I came across in a PDF comparing how SSIS and Informatica handle messaging.

SSIS includes a Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) connection manager that enables
connectivity to MSMQ message queues. Coupled with this is a bidirectional Message Queue
task that enables an SSIS package to push messages onto and pop messages off a message
queue. The messages can be in the form of text, files or the contents of SSIS variables.
SQL Server Service Broker which is included with SQL Server 2005 (and therefore with SSIS)
adds asynchronous messaging functionality to database applications. Service Broker queues
accessible from any application able to issue T-SQL code which includes SSIS.